# open windshield during landing/takeoff

Tags: landing, takeoff

In India, during landing and takeoff the passangers are asked to open the windshield.
I googled the reason but couldn't find any technical logic.
I am also not sure if this practice is universal.
Can anyone explain reason.

Comment: It is a matter of safety. In case of an accident, being able to see out the windows will make it easier for crew and passengers to orient themselves, for example to spot a fire on one side of the aircraft.

Comment: Agree...This is duplicate...Auto suggestions didn't work in android app hence couldn't notice it.

Comment: This is not the [windshield](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/boeing-issues-windshield-warning/) that is open, but the windows shades.

Comment: Yes, the windshield is the thing at the front of the airplane the pilots look through.  Some military planes have anti-flash curtains (you pull those shut in cruise when flying on instruments and nukes are flying; it's pretty dumb to be blinded by a distant H-bomb flash that couldn't harm you otherwise).  But you're supposed to have those open on takeoff, they really hammered that home in training :)